404 Not Found error while invoking the chart data reading api (eg http://localhost:8090/api/vi/chart/138)
Unable to fecth chart information using X-Guesttoken information on headers.
we were able to fetch dashboard using same guesttoken
We are expecting http status 200 on http://localhost:8090/api/vi/chart/138 using same header as like dashboard,datasets, charts etc
